# Dates not working properly after moving VB.NET project to new computer

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access

I have an application that reads and writes to an Access 2016 DB, I have just moved my DB and project to a new computer and now when I run a SELECT command from VB it reads the date backwards (i.e 07/11/2018 should be 7th November but VB reads it as 11th July).

The problem is definitely with VB rather than Access as when I filter the date field by month in Access 07/11/2018 filters correctly as November.

Is there some sort of global setting that needs to be set?

Here is the code:

```
        Public Shared Sub Update_All()

        Dim connectString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & MainForm.mainDir & "\eBase.accdb"
        Dim cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connectString)

        cn.Open()

        Dim selectString As String = "Select e_date, e_name FROM Results WHERE eRats Is Null Order By e_date ASC;"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(selectString, cn)
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While (reader.Read())
            Update_R(reader("e_date").ToString, reader("e_name").ToString)
        End While

        reader.Close()
        cn.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Does your new computer have a different system language than your old one? The parsing formats change depending on the language of the machine (or the threads).

Comment: It sounds like you're quite possibly using a string representation of the date instead of the `DateTime` value. Please post the code you're using.

Comment: `The problem is definitely with VB rather than Access`.  A good craftsman never blames his tools.

Comment: We probably need to see `Update_R`, but the fact that you are passing the date value as ToString doesn't look promising.

Comment: I'm using the same language as my old system (English), I am using a string of the date but it's read from the database and it worked on my old system.

Comment: Problem solved, the region format in Windows was set to English (US), rather than English (UK), hence the backwards dates!

Comment: Then your code is sloppy as it should work independently of that setting.

Answer (score 1):

Without your code, we have to guess.

It sounds like you filter using string concatenating. If so, apply an invariant format to the filter value:

```
"Select * From YourTable Where DateField = #" & FilterDateValue.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "#"
```

You will be told by many to use *parameters* to prevent this kind of trouble.